# Python Multiprocessing - Tricky use-case, includes passing arguments

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm having problems distributing my function in parallel.

**Problem Statement:** I have 2 lists of coordinate pairs, `dfC` and `dfO`. For each obs in `dfC`, I'm counting how many `dfO`'s fall within radius `r`. *I currently have a working function*, but I'm trying to see if I can process this in parallel.

The catch is this: `dfC` can be split up and processed individually... but `dfO` needs to be 100% on each worker. My approach has been, let me just get this working in parallel first - and then I'll worry about how to distribute a full copy of `dfO` to the workers. Unless someone can help me tackle both?

First, here's the code to set everything up:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Pool, process
import traceback
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

# create 2 dataframes with random "coordinates"
dfC=pd.DataFrame(np.random.np.random.randint(0,100,size=(50,2)), columns=list('xy'))
dfO=pd.DataFrame(np.random.np.random.randint(0,100,size=(500,2)), columns=list('jk'))
```

Here's an example of what `dfC` looks like, `dfO` will look similar

```
+----+----+
|  x |  y |
+----+----+
| 35 |  5 |
+----+----+
| 96 | 18 |
+----+----+
| 23 | 25 |
+----+----+
| 20 | 7  |
+----+----+
| 74 | 54 |
+----+----+
```

Next, here is the function that works like charm. Instead of passing in all the arguments separately, I'm actually doing it this way on purpose - to prepare for a main function to call these in parallel (and I couldn't find a way for multiprocessing to do it otherwise).

```
# this function works on dfC, and adds a row which counts the number
# of objects in dfO which are within radius r
def worker_job(args):
    try:
        dfC, dfO, newcol, r = args

        mxC=dfC.as_matrix()
        mxO = dfO.as_matrix()

        # magic tree stuff
        C_Tree = cKDTree(mxC)
        O_Tree = cKDTree(mxO)

        listoflists = C_Tree.query_ball_tree(O_Tree, r, p=2.0, eps=0.0)

        counts=[]
        for i in listoflists:
            counts.append(len(i))

        s = pd.Series(counts)

        dfC[newcol] = s.values

    except:
        raise
        traceback.print_exc()
    else:
        return dfC
```

If I create my arguments like this:
`args=[dfC,dfO,"new_column_name",3]`

It works perfectly when I run it by itself:
`worker_job(args)`

```
+----+----+-----------------+
|  x |  y | new_column_name |
+----+----+-----------------+
| 35 |  5 |        4        |
+----+----+-----------------+
| 96 | 18 |        1        |
+----+----+-----------------+
| 23 | 25 |        0        |
+----+----+-----------------+
| 20 |  7 |        1        |
+----+----+-----------------+
| 74 | 54 |        2        |
+----+----+-----------------+
```

Now, I try and build the function that will control the parallel workers and run this thing in parallel. Here's my best effort:

```
# this function should control the multiprocessing
def Run_Parallel(Function, Num_Proc, args):
    try:
        pool = Pool(Num_Proc)
        parts = pool.map(Function,args)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

        results_df = pd.concat(parts)

    except:
        pool.close()
        pool.terminate()
        traceback.print_exc()
    else:
        return results_df
```

It won't work. `Run_Parallel(worker_job,2,args)` throws an error about `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)`. Something must be happening to that list of arguments as it goes through the wrapper.

I'm looking for guidance on this error specifically, and bonus points for anyone who knows how to solve the bigger problem - which is I need my pools to contain 100% of `dfO` and just a subset of `dfC` for the sake of efficiency.

Comment: `Pool.map` expects an `iterable`. so you have to put your `args` list inside another list and then pass it to the `map` function. you might notice that it's not different than calling the `worker_job` function directly. so you gonna have to restructure your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was to pass the arguments as a list of lists. This also solved the other problem of splitting up the dataframe (I thought pool took care of this by default, but it does not).

The correct function should look like:

```
# this function should control the multiprocessing
def Run_Parallel(Function, Num_Proc, args):
    dfC, dfO, newcol, r = args

    # to make lists of lists
    argslist=[]
    dfOlist=[]
    dfClist=[]
    resultlist=[]

    # split dfC into parts
    Cparts=np.array_split(dfC, Num_Proc)

    # build the lists
    for i in range(Num_Proc):
        argslist.append([Cparts[i],dfO,newcol,r])


    try:
        pool = Pool(Num_Proc)
        parts = pool.map(Function,argslist)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

        results_df = pd.concat(parts)

    except:
        pool.close()
        pool.terminate()
        traceback.print_exc()
    else:
        return results_df
```